# Image corrupt or truncated in NHibernate when using byte[] and varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, arrays

I need to save a jpg image to database 
in the database type of this property is nvarchar(max)
so i need to serialize and deserialize this property like this:

```
 private byte[] HexStringToObject(string value)
    {
        SoapHexBinary shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse(value);
        return shb.Value;
    }

 private string ObjectToHexString(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";

        SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary((byte[])value);
        return shb.ToString();
    }
```

but there is a problem,, I dont know the problem is related to serialize or deserialize method
just when I want to see this image via:

```
 public FileResult Initialpicture(int? propertyId)
    {
        if (propertyId == null)
            return null;
        IProperty image = Repository<IProperty>.Get(propertyId);
        if (image.Value == null)
            return null;
        return File((byte[])image.Value, "image/jpg");//Get of Value use deserialize method to get byte[]
```

and in the browser i just can see small part of image,and the error " Image corrupt or truncated:"
        }

what is the problem?

Comment: nvarchar(max) ?? did you mean varbinary(max) ?

Comment: You can use the FILESTREAM if you use the Sql Server 2008 or higher.

Comment: +1 to Mitch Wheat's comment: Don't store binary data in a text (varchar) column. Please, please learn the differences between text data and raw binary strings — not enough people out there understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your database or your ORM if you have any, will truncate the byte array for example to 12000 bytes.

Comment: yes it was right,and I was using hibernate and by using this kinda mapping every thing is working fine: Map(p => p.Value)
                .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
                .CustomType<string>()
                .CustomSqlType("nvarchar(MAX)")
                .Length(2147483647)